# Initializing a class object as wrong type

Tags: c++

I have this code and I'd like to ask - how is it possible to initialize a class object with new int() without getting an exception?
When I print the value of the object it prints junk but I still don't understand how this assignment is possible.
What exactly happens when you use new int(value)? doesn't it create space for an int and initializes it with value?

```
class A {
    static A* first;
    static A* last;
    A *prev, *next;
public:
    A() : prev(last), next(nullptr) {
        cout << "A ctor" << endl;
        if (last) last->next = this;
        last = this;
        if (!first) first = this;
    }
    virtual ~A() {
        if (prev) prev->next = next;
        if (next) next->prev = prev;
        if (first == this) first = next;
        if (last == this) last = prev;
    }
    static void printAll() {
        if (first) cout << *first;
        else cout << "list is empty" << endl;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const A&a) {
        a.printSelf();
        if (a.next) out << *(a.next);
        else out << endl;
        return out;
    }
    virtual void printSelf() const = 0;
};

template<class T>
class B : public A {
    T * t;
public:
    B(const T& _t) : t(new T(_t)) { cout << "B ctor" << endl; }
    virtual ~B() {
        cout << "Dtor B" << endl;
        cout << *this;
        delete t;
    }
    virtual void printSelf()const override {
        cout << *t << ' ';
    }
};
A* A::first = nullptr;
A * A::last = nullptr;

int main() {

    B<int*>b1 = new int(5);
    b1.printSelf(); //prints junk (b1.t value)
    cout << endl;
    cout << typeid(b1).name() << endl; //prints class B<int*>
}
```

Comment: This is common C++ feature, constructor will be called automatically according to the parameter type. If you'd like to prevent it - add `explicit` to constructor, i.e. `explicit B(const T& _t)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for `explicit` keyword:

Without explicit, the compiler will try implicit conversion between types using the constructor:

```
class Test
{
public:
Test(int){}
};

Test t = 42;
```

If this is not supposed to happens, then you can use `explicit` (I personally recommend to use it by default on each non-copy single-argument constructor.

```
class Test
{
public:
explicit Test(int){}
};

Test t = 42; //error here
```

---

In your case, `T` is a pointer to `int`, thus, `new int(5)` will generate an integer on heap and return a pointer to it. This is a valid argument for `B`.

Looking inside your constructor:

```
B(const T& _t) : t(new T(_t)) { cout << "B ctor" << endl; }
```

your receive a `_t` which is a pointer to int (e.g. 0xabcd -> 5), and you initialize `this->t`with a new pointer to pointer to int, initialized with `0xabcd`. That is:

```
B(const int*& _t): t(new int*(_t))...
// t is &(0xabcd), *t is 0xabcd, **t is 5
```

Then printing `*t`:

```
cout << 0xabcd << ' '; // printing the memory address, not the value 5.
```

You can try this instead:

```
cout << **t << ' '; // Print 5
```

But... it's probably better to solve the double allocation and remove the memory leak:

```
B<int>b1 = 5;
```

Comment: Thanks!
So basically the right side of `B<int*>b1 = new int(5);` executes first (creates an int pointer to 5) according to T value of the right side which is int*, and then enters B<int*>'s copy constructor?
And is that the reason why the line 'B<int>b1=new int(5) wouldn't execute for ex.?

Comment: You don't have any B copy constructor `B( const B&)`. Your line allocate an integer on the heap, and set it value to 5. Then, it passes it address to B constructor. The problem is that `T`is `*int` instead of `int`

Comment: Ok thank you. 
Just last question: assuming i have this code: `B<int> b1=5;`,
and then `B<int> * b2=new B<int>(b1)`. what will it do? normally it should call a copy constructor, create a new object similar to b1 and return its value to *b2 right? what would it do in this code's case?

Comment: No, your second line `B<int> * b2=new B<int>(b1)` is creating a simple pointer to `B<int>` and set it to a newly allocated on heap instance of `B<int>`; it create one single object of `B`, and save it memory address. To call a copy constructor, you need some line like: `B<int> b1(5); B<int> b2 = b1;` I also recommend you to "never" use `new`, but rather smart pointers: `auto bPtr = std::make_unique<B<int>>(5);`, this way you don't create memory leaks. Finally, think about accepting my answer.

Comment: Here are some examples of constructors, destructors and pointers: https://onlinegdb.com/HyqJah6Jd

Comment: By the way, did you worked with Java before? if so, forget what you know for C++: objects are not always pointers, you have stack and heap objects, and no garbage collection.

Comment: This isn't my code, I know it's shitty. it's from a past exam and I just need to understand the syntax and what it does. 
And I still don't get what (b1) does in the second line. 
So just to be clear, the second line creates a pointer to a B<int> with new memory allocated for a B<int>? so what does the (b1) do? because when i created a copy constructor and ran this code it did call it..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227852/discussion-between-adrian-maire-and-itamar-ivri). (Let me know if you can't)